# Docker breaks network bridging to virtual machines

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, docker

After installing `docker` I can no longer access my VMs running on my Linux machine. The VMs are up and running but other hosts can no longer access them at all. Has anybody already encountered this problem before and could help with these two questions?

- Why is this the case?
- How can I reconfigure my system to again correctly bridge to the VMs?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Docker breaks bridge networking by changing the system's IPTABLES firewalls when it starts. This is a known problem without a decent solution.

See: 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=865975

A solution from here is:
https://anteru.net/blog/2017/docker-kvm-and-iptables/index.html

Create a file /etc/docker/daemon.json with the following contents:

```
{
    "iptables" : false
}
```

WARNING: This "fix" may have serious security implications so beware. I think the best solution would be for docker to create and manage its own chains in IPTABLES and leave the system ones alone.

Comment: This prevents docker containers egress traffic